# how can i access Shared Folder for all users in citrix sharefile?

Tags: sharefile

How to access Shared folder for all the users in citrix sharefile using either rest api or java sdk??I am able to access my Files and folders for all the users.

Answer (score -1):

This is in scala, but you should be able to figure it out.

```
val sfue = new SFUsersEntity(apiClient)
Future { sfue.getAllSharedFolders().execute().getFeed().asScala.toList }
```